# Long difference between server response and browser result with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action with this kind of code :

```
  Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship).limit(2000).to_a
  render nothing: true
```

The server answer gives :

```
method=GET path=/timesheet_reports/rest_hours format=html controller=Company::Timesheet::ReportsController action=rest_hours status=200 duration=2106.43 view=3.68 db=23.75
```

But, in the browser, the rendering take 6 sec (for a blank) page. There is a difference of 4 seconds and it increase if I change `2000` for an higher value.

It's correct if I remove the `includes` or the `to_a`. It's the same if I do :

```
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship).limit(2000).each(&:id)
```

Removing the includes is fastest even if there is a n+1 query problem.

I'm using ruby 2.3 and Rails 4.2.

I suppose there is a problem with memory allocation but I don't know how to to solve it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using includes? What the SQL looks like? 
Maybe if you read the sql you will see :

```
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship)
# SELECT "work_period".* FROM "work_period"
# SELECT "ship".* FROM "ship" WHERE "ship"."work_period_id" IN (....)
```

The cost for the query can be huge if you have lot's of rows!

Also because your result can be big. It costs to manipulate huge array in ruby.

Try to use as much as possible active record methods on your data before using ruby, also for example:

```
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship).limit(2000).each(&:id)
# use select if you need AR object
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship).limit(2000).select(:id)
# or pluck if you need the list of value in column
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship).limit(2000).pluck(:id)
```

Also check the log when you page is accessed to see if you don't have N+1. The gem [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) can also help you.
If it's doesn't help you. Use [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler).

Further reading:

- http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html
- http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you relations are indexed. Moreover, use pluck instead of each.

```
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship).limit(2000).pluck(:id)
# Depending which ID you need
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.includes(:ship).limit(2000).pluck('ships.id')
```

If indexes are fine, please double check if all data is necessary for you. If all you need from your relation is just an ID, feel free to use joins and select only the id.

```
Timesheet::WorkPeriod.joins(:ship).limit(2000).pluck('ships.id')
# You may also want left join
Timesheet::WorkPeriod
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN ships ON ships.work_period_id = work_periods.ids')
  .limit(2000).pluck('ships.id')
```